# Flutter Web and multiple deployment error

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web

I am trying to set up a production/development of a `Flutter` web app for `Firebase.`   I am able to deploy to the first one I configured (production) but not to the second (development).  I am getting this error:

```
 === Deploying to 'my-app-dev'...
 
 i  deploying hosting i  hosting[my-app-dev]: beginning deploy... i 
 hosting[my-app-dev]: found 27 files in build/web ⠋  hosting: uploading
 new files [3/21] (14%) Error: Task
 1c5e4be41a8a2901d8c9ae4edb5c2bd26c5c4d0564d732a3ce2bef7c6c27bcb0
 failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts, with error: The "path"
 argument must be of type string. Received undefined ⠸  hosting:
 uploading new files [4/21] (19%)
```

I am running the following commands:

```
firebase use my-app-dev
flutterfire configure --project=my-app-dev
flutter build web
firebase deploy
```

Note: if I use `my-app-prod` instead it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and I solved it with the next two steps:

1. remove the `.firebase` folder from the root folder of your project
2. try to deploy your project again with `firebase deploy`

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my firebase tools by running follwing command:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Then I deleted all firebase files in the root of my project.
Again ran:

```
firebase init
```

Completed all steps for firebase connection and then again tried to deployed by web using following command:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

And everything started to work fine.